# creating a numpy array filled with a character

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is there an alternative way to create a numpy array filled with a character, e.g.:

```
p = np.array( [' '] * 12 )
```

Is there a way to use `np.full(...)`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes [`np.full`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.full.html) could be used with the correct datatype (string) being mentioned with it, like so -

```
np.full((12), [' '],dtype=str)
```

You can also use [`np.repeat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) -

```
np.repeat([' '], 12)
```

Comment: You can do it without the one-item list: `np.full(12, ' ', dtype=str)`

Comment: @askewchan Thanks! That works too. Being a minor change, I would keep it as it is for now.